# Wrapping data classes in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I wanted to ask about data classes in kotlin.
Suppose I have 2 data classes , data class A and data class B , I want to wrap my data class A around data class B.

Is this a case of Inheritance or inline class , I am kind of new to Kotlin .

```
data class A(
var x1:Float?,
var y1:Float?
)

data class B(
var x:Float?,
var y:Float?,
// other variables and methods
)
```

Thanks

Comment: It is neither. But please show your code if you want to ask questions about it.

Comment: i have updated the question with code.

Comment: First of all, your code won't even compile, because a `data` class must have at least one primary constructor property (`val` or `var`) parameter and there is no such type as `float` in Kotlin, there's `Float`. Secondly, your class `B` has nothing to do with the class `A`. It neither inherits from it nor uses its instances.

Comment: @jsamol thank you , I have updated the code accordingly .

Comment: Still there is no relation between `A` and `B`, they are just separate classes. If you mean to inherit `var x: Float?` and `var y: Float?` from `A` then you can't do it as long as `A` is a `data` class, because `data` classes are final and can't be extended. You could do that if the `A` class would be an `open` class or an `abstract` one, or an `interface` as [Adam Kobor mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58029505/11342519). If that's not the case, please explain a little further what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can't inherit a Kotlin data class from an other data class, but you can use interfaces or abstract classes and your data classes can implement/extend these:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract var valueA: Int
}

interface B {
    val valueB: Int
}

data class C(
    val value2: String,
    override var valueA: Int
) : A()

data class D(
    override val valueB: Int,
    val valueD: String
) : B
```